# column value can not be null

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

problem :- it is inserting data in table blank even after using form_validation
and i tried if condition for checking cat_title then it works
so basically i want to use it without using if contidtion.
i think the problem is in my controller.

this one is my controller

```
class Cat extends CI_Controller {
//insert in table    
        public function addcat()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_title', 'Category', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                        {
                                $this->load->view('admin/addcategory');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $this->load->view('admin/addcategory');
                        }
            $data['cat_title'] = $this->input->post('cat_title');
            $this->cat_model->create_cat('category',$data);
        }
// print data
    public function showcat()
        {
            $data['result'] = $this->cat_model->get_cat(); 
            $this->load->view('admin/showcategory',$data);
        }
}

?>
```

this is my model

```
<?php


class Cat_model extends CI_Model {
    // get table from database
    public function get_cat(){

       $query = $this->db->get('category');

        return $query->result();

    }

    public function create_cat($table,$data){
        //insert data in table
       $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);

        return $query;

    } 
}
?>
```

and this my form in html i create form using codeigniter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/admincss');?>

</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>

    <?php $this->load->view('includes/adminheader');?>
    <section>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mrg-top">
            <div class="row">
        <?php $this->load->view('includes/header_nav');?>
                <div class="col-lg-10">

                    <h1>Add Category</h1>
                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    <?php echo form_open('cat/addcat'); ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Type in below Input</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title">
                        </div>
                        <a href=""><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button></a>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/adminfooter');?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Column set as nullable in MySQL ....

Comment: i did that still it is sending null value.

Comment: Maybe stay on the browser cache remove cache  ,did you it ?

Comment: also tried it removing browser cache

Comment: when i start using null a single null data saved in table

Comment: after that i can't input data in table

Answer (score 0):

MySQL column is not null set it for example ,if column be nullable your code works

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY mycolumn varchar(255) null;
```